# How to sort capacities column in Datatables

Tags: javascript, sorting, datatables

i have a datatable with capacities column like this :

```
<table id="datatable" class="table">
<thead> <tr> <th>N</th> <th>capa</th> </tr> </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2 Go</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1 To</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>320 Go</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2 To</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>500 Go</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').dataTable({
    'aaSorting': [],
    'iDisplayLength': 50,
    'aLengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 'Tous']]
    });
}); 
</script>
```

and I am trying to sort it to get this result :

```
2 Go
320 Go
500 Go
1 To
2 To
```

But can't figure out how to do it from reading the sorting plugins docs.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, can you clear up what is the criteria of the column sorting you are trying to achieve? If you want descending sort of the 2nd column you cant do it without removing the number before the string 'Go' or 'To'. Unless you want to handle and override the sort function stripping numeric values from column content

Comment: The default soting methof of datatables sorts only numbers then i have this result : 
`1 To
2 Go
2 To
320 Go
500 Go`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. 
I'm putting my answer which works well for me.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"file-size-pre": function (a) {
    var x = a.substring(0, a.length - 2);
    var x_unit = (a.substring(a.length - 2, a.length) == "Go" ? 1000 : (a.substring(a.length - 2, a.length) == "To" ? 1000000 : 1));
    return parseInt(x * x_unit, 10);
},
    "file-size-asc": function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
},
    "file-size-desc": function (a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
}
});

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#datatable').dataTable({
    'columnDefs': [{ 'type': 'file-size', 'targets': 1 }],
        'aaSorting': [],
        'iDisplayLength': 50,
        'aLengthMenu': [ [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, -1],  [10, 25, 50, 100, 500, 'Tous'] ]
});
});
```

Here is a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/cu9taqfg/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort on the text part of the 'capa' column.  You can achieve this by adding a column containing the text field, hiding it, and using [iDataSort](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#iDataSort) to sort on the hidden column when the 'capa' column header is clicked.

First, add the new text-only column to each row:

```
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2 Go</td>
   <td>Go</td>
</tr>
```

In the datatable initialisation code, use `aoColumns` to specify the column definitions:

```
...
'iDisplayLength': 50,
'aoColumns': [{},{ "iDataSort": 2 }, {'bVisible':false }],
...
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/HEDvf/2377/)

`Update`: so it sounds like you want to sort on the text column THEN the int column, it would have been helpful if you had just stated that earlier.

```
'aoColumns': [{},{ "aDataSort": [2], "aTargets": [ 0, 2 ] }, {'bVisible': false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }],
```

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/HEDvf/2384/)

Comment: Thanks but this func sorts capacities in an alphabetic order, but we have 1 Mo < 1 Go <1 To

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it

http://jsfiddle.net/jkwoaj3x/1/

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
     "columns": [
            null,
         { "orderDataType": "custom-sort" }
        ]
});
```

and this is your custom sort func

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['custom-sort'] = function  ( settings, col )
{
return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
    console.log($(td).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ''));
    return $(td).text().replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
} );
}
```

is it your solution?

Comment: Sorry, but i have to sort capacities too, beacause we have 1 Mo< 1 Go <1 To

Comment: Ok now it's a little more clear, the order function extension is customizable, actually I only tried to strip numbers from the column content, in the same way, you can replace the capacity achronim, substitute it with a value (for example it can be: 100 for Mo, 1000 for Go ecc ecc..) and multiply for the number so you have the resulting order.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a table with all source data in gigas but render it differently without change nested data thanks to render in columnDefs option , it will use the built-in sort for numbers that works very well

http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

I always do that when i want to display sentences and still have sortable column and it is very efficient

```
    <table id="datatable" class="table">
    <thead> <tr> <th>N</th> <th>capa</th> </tr> </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1000 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>320</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>



//targets is the number of the column you want render (here number 1)

//care full!!!! use DataTable and not datatable, second is old and doesn't have all options, if you don't want use fnRender
    table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
     "columnDefs":{
                    "targets": 1, "visible": true, "searchable": true
                    , "render": function (data, type, row) {
                       if (type == "display") {
                        if (data > 1000)
                            return ((data / 1000) + " To");
                        else
                            return (data + " Go");
                       }
                      return data;
                    },
                  };
    });
```

It is best solution !